# What does "glimmer" mean in this context? (Warning Spoilers for a movie "The Beach" 2000)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm watching the movie "The Beach" 2000, and there is a scene, in which a character played by Leonardo Dicaprio, tells a story of a shark attack to a group of people. He survived the attack because it was a very small shark,and he was able, as a result, to provide food for the people who he is speaking to, and who were very hungry because they had no access to any source of food at the time.

"At that instant, I knew it was either shark or me. The shark knew it. I knew it. But jeez..God. It's nothing personal, right? It's just the way the world works. It's nature. But if I remember correctly...in that last **glimmer** of it's eyes.. there was a moment between us.. where he said "hey Richard, man,enjoy your dinner"

2. A faint manifestation or indication; a trace: a glimmer of understanding.(source thefreedictionary)

Is this the correct definition?

Comment: A [glimmer](https://www.lexico.com/definition/glimmer) of **light** or life. *Shine faintly with a wavering light.*

Comment: That definition works. The glimmer in someone's eyes.

Comment: ...the last glimmer of **its** eyes. No apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that definition is appropriate. However the correct phrase is:

> glimmer of its eyes

(no apostrophe).

Comment: Meaning. of course, 'the last moment that its eyes showed any sign of life'.

Comment: Kate so "glimmer" in "glimmer of its eyes" means a sign of life and not the sign of what the shark was thinking and going to say to him?  Is this a set phrase that always means that? e.i When I hear "glimmer of its eyes" can I know for certain that it means "a sign or last trace of life in persons or animals eyes?